# Is it possible to show custom graphs in facebook messenger bot?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I am working on a chatbot for banking sector. is it **possible to show custom graphs** (with raw personal data) in reply to the user using messenger api?

i am searching for this but did not find anything related

if its possible  to achieve than please help

if not possible than any alternative ways for the same  will be helpful

Thank you

Comment: Just to be clear, you are not talking about custom Open Graph stories here (those have been deprecated a while ago), but just an ordinary “graph” of some data? Well you’d have to create that as an image on your end, and then send it as attachment.

Comment: yes is there any articles or anything to achieve this?

Comment: SO is not the place to ask for external resources like tutorials or explanation articles. If you don’t know how to dynamically create image files with the graph library you are using, then go check the documentation. If you have not even settled on a library to use yet, then doing this kind of research is your responsibility at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing built-in to the Messenger Platform API for creating graphs. The best option would be to build the graph server-side then send it as a message attachment in jpg format.

If you're looking to create a more full-featured experience, you can show send a message template with a web_url button that opens the graph in the webview.